# How to Remove dynamic Parent <tr> via OnClick of child <input>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, dom-manipulation

I'm adding the `<tr>` via a Javascript var:

```
var txtBox = "<tr id='dynTR'><td><input type='text' class='textBoxes' /></td><td><input type='text' class='textBoxes' value='0' /></td><td><input type='button' value='-' /></td></tr>";
```

With my function being:

```
function AddTR(table) {
            $(table).append(txtBox);
        }
```

My table structure (along with the button for the function) in the HTML being:

```
<table id="tblTest" class="testTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td>Remove TR</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
        <input type="Button" id="btnTest" value="Add Table Row" onclick="AddTR($('#tblTest'))" />
```

So how do I go about using the `.remove()` function in jQuery to get rid of the parent tag without accidentally removing all `<tr id='dynTR'>` tags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering this one is the remove button:

```
<input type='button' value='-' />
```

The following will do:

```
$('#tblTest input[type="button"]').click(function () {
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

I'd suggest you use jQuery event handlers instead of using inline `onclick` and friends. `$(this)` is the jQuery object of the button that was clicked, `.closest()` will look in the parents of the button and find the first `tr`, then remove it.

[jsFiddle by @ShadowWizard](http://jsfiddle.net/XP2Gf/1)

The best way would be to change the HTML for your remove button:

```
<input type='button' value='-' class='removeButton' />
```

so you can target your remove button like this:

```
$('#tblTest .removeButton').click(...
```

This is better because with the previous example, every possible `input type="button"` in the table would get the event, even though we just need it on these special ones (not a problem if there are no other buttons in the table).

Comment: Nice, was going to offer solution using `parent("td").parent("tr")` your way is obviously better. I have made a quick test case as well: http://jsfiddle.net/XP2Gf/1/ :)

Comment: @Shadow Thanks, let me just put it into my answer.

Comment: Cheers @baz glad I could also lend some help. :)

Comment: Awesome! It worked! I think I missed something the first time I tried applying your solution, but after the second attempt I got it. I think I just missed some class/id referencing.

Answer (score 4):

bazmegakapa answer should do the trick. Also you should really avoid using inline Javascript, it's generally bad practise. Instead do:

```
$('#btnTest').click(function() { AddTR($('#tblTest')); });
```

Also to keep up with the convention of jQuery using the correct scope of the element object, you could do:

```
$('#btnTest').click(function() { AddTR.call($('#tblTest')[0]); });
```

Then in your AddTR function you can simply reference the element table as `this`

```
function AddTR() {
    $(this).append(txtBox);
}
```

It keeps things predictable and follows the same convention.

---

#### Hang on a minute....

In theory although the `AddTR()` function is adding a table row, it's a bit misleading because all it's doing is just appending an element to that context. What you really want to do is just what the function says; **add a table row!** instead your doing

```
var txtBox = "<tr id='dynTR'><td><input type='text' class='textBoxes' /></td><td><input type='text' class='textBoxes' value='0' /></td><td><input type='button' value='-' /></td></tr>";
```

Which is rather ugly and will cause some changes if you change your table row structures. Instead, use `.clone` to help you:

```
function AddTR() {
   $(this).append($('tr:last').clone());
}
```

**See fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/6NUK3/1/

Comment: +1 good advice. jQuery offers a very easy way to attach event handlers. Inline event handlers will just cause you further problems (and behaviour should not go into the HTML markup).

Comment: I see, thanks for the advice. I haven't ventured much in front-end programming, but reading your comments gives me a better understanding of front-end development.

Comment: No problem Erick. It's good that you want to learn more about front end and jQuery, it's a dream to work with. I know you've accepted baz's answer, but anyhow I've updated my answer for a more optimized method of what your trying to do.

Comment: Awesome. Although, I think that there should be a condition in that if the <tr> doesn't match the last <tr> it shouldn't clone but create that row. Anyway, that's just me since a user could click the remove button and end-up cloning the title <tr>.

Comment: Well with a few structural changes, by correctly adding the header in the `<thead>` section with `<th>` and the body of the table inside `<tbody>` you can do this very easily with `:not(:first-child)` selector -- see here: http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/6NUK3/4/ -- I've added the feature of it resetting the input values so it's empty on the newly added row.